# Expression or term which means 'to argue illogically only to argue'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Would someone advise if there's any Expression or term which means 'to argue illogically only to argue'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by illogically (i.e. if it's illogical to be arguing rather than making an illogical argument) then you might be able to say **Eristic**:

> Argument that aims to successfully dispute another's argument, rather than searching for truth.

--[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eristic)